# Is there an analytic solution for the following non-linear equation $x'(t) = a(t) + b\, x(t) + c\,x^3(t)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

Here $b, c$ are constants. Of course there exists locally a solution by the Picard-Lindelöf theorem but I'm looking for an explicit expression.

In fact, this question comes from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4044652/92038) but I changed the notation (the present $a(t)$ corresponds to $f(t)$). There may be another way to solve the matrix equation (of the other post) but solving the present equation seemed the most natural to me.

**Attempts and thoughts:**

1. Our equation looks like Riccati's but with a third power instead of a second. So I thought about look for a solution of the form $x(t) + y(t)$ with $x$ satisfying $x'(t) =  b\, x(t) + c\,x^3(t)$ so that $y$ has to satisfy another equation. However that latter is even more complex than the original one.\
   More generally, this idea of introducing a new unknown but additively (I also thought about doing something like variation of constants, or looking at a solution of the form $x(t) y(t)$...) seems to me like an attempt to exploit the different behavior of l.h.s. vs. r.h.s.. The first is linear, the second one should be related to translation of polynomials, i.e. Taylor expansion.
2. At first, assuming that $x(t)$ never vanishes, I had written $a(t)= x^3(t) \times \tilde{a}(t)$ which formally makes the equation look like Bernouilli's with $\tilde{c}:= c + \tilde{a}(t)$, but solving it would just give an integral form of the original equation, once we have reinjected the dependence in the unknown $x(t)$ within $\tilde{a}(t):= \frac{a(t)}{x^3(t)}$...
3. Look for $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and see such that
   $$ \frac{d}{dt}T\big(t,x(t),y(t)\big)=a(t) + b\,T\big(t,x(t),y(t)\big) + c\, T\big(t,x(t),y(t)\big)^3 $$
   Assuming that $\dot{x}= bx + cx^3$, one has
   $$  \partial_t T + \dot{x}\, \partial_x T +  \dot{y}\, \partial_y T =  \partial_t T + \big(bx + cx^3 \big) \partial_x T +  \dot{y}\, \partial_y T = \text{R.h.s.}$$
   $$ \partial_t T  +  \dot{y}\, \partial_y T = a(t) + b \big(T - x\,  \partial_x T\big) + c \big(T^3 - x^3\,  \partial_x T\big) $$
   Making the choice to impose $T^3 \overset{!}{=} x^3\,  \partial_x T$ let me to try $T(x,y)= \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2 y}}$...

Comment: yes, but if you know how to solve it for $a$ constant, I would also take it...

Comment: It's called an abel equation of the first kind! Found it on wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation_of_the_first_kind

Comment: Waouh, thanks a lot. Collaborative thinking, that's really a game changer!!! I may try to write a specific answer if not too tedious.\\ In fact I had another idea: use the explicit answer of the linked equation, write an analytic expansion and assuming that $a(t)$ is also analytic, one would at least have a series solution

Comment: There is no general solution, the paper the wiki is quoting only gives a transformation to the Abel equation of the first kind of the normal form, i.e. $u'=u^3+\phi(\zeta)$.